# Ruby (rails) non-blocking recursive algorithm?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, recursion

I've written the following pseudo-ruby to illustrate what I'm trying to do. I've got some computers, and I want to see if anything's connected to them. If nothing is connected to them, try again for another two attempts, and if that's the still case, shut it down.

This is for a big deployment so this recursive timer could be running for hundreds of nodes. I just want to check, is this approach sound? Will it generate tonnes of threads and eat up lots of RAM while blocking the worker processes? (I expect it will be running as a `delayed_job`)

```
check_status(0)


def check_status(i)
  if instance.connected.true? then return

  if instance.connected.false? and i < 3
    wait.5.minutes
    instance.check_status(i+1)
  else 
    instance.shutdown
    return
  end
end
```

Comment: Avoid recursion if you can, it's hungry for RAM.

Comment: Recursion itself does not automagically generate threads. This code is not eager to resources at all.

Comment: BTW, should not `instance.shutdown` be ensured?

Comment: I am not sure if using Ruby for that task is preferable. I'm thinking of global interpreter lock that restricts simultaneous execution of Ruby code in one MRI instance. Would you use another programming language for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is not going to be a large problem when the maximum recursion depth here is 3. It should be fine. Recursing a method does not create threads, but each call does store more information about the call stack, and eventually the resources used for that storage could run out. Not after 3 calls though, that is quite safe.

However, there is no need for recursion to solve your problem. The following loop should do just as well:

```
def check_status
  return if instance.connected.true?
  2.times do 
    wait.5.minutes
    return if instance.connected.true?
  end
  instance.shutdown
end
```

Comment: Actually that's much easier to understand, thanks so much!

Comment: @cjm2671: See Elyasin's answer and my comment on it. Individual workers in `delayed_worker` may block on calls to `wait` method (I cannot find the definition of that method, not 100% sure on that). In which case to increase scale when you expect significant delay getting connections, you can run many workers - most of which will be idle. Or you may want to look at a more sophisticated threaded worker library depending on actual delay times and total numbers of delayed jobs you need to have concurrently.

Answer (score 2):

You got answers from other users already. However, since you are waiting 5 minutes at least two times, you might consider using another language or change the design.

Ruby (MRI) has a global interpreter lock, which restricts parallel execution of Ruby code. MRI is not parallel. You risk to be inefficient with this.

- Consider using threads (a reasonable number of thread pools might make sense), probably fed by a queue with tasks
- Make sure you don't wait 5 minutes. Instead put them to *sleep* for that time. This way other threads can execute, while some are *sleeping*/*waiting*
- You could also consider using jRuby, since jRuby has true parallelism (MRI is restricted by the GIL, thus it is not truly parallel)
- Consider using another programming language that might be more performant

Comment: If OP is using delayed_job for this, then they currently would need to run enough worker processes to cover combined wait times. There may be other better methods, including looking at a thread-based worker. Ruby MRI can deal efficiently with many parallel threads, when the majority of them are sleeping or waiting on I/O (because in MRI implementation these behaviours *are* handled in true parallel fashion).

Answer (score 1):

If it's running via `delayed_job` why not use the gem's functionality to implement what you want? I, for one, would go for something like the following. No need to sleep the delayed jobs or anything.

```
class CheckStatusJob

  def before(job)
    @job = job
  end

  def perform
    if instance.connected.true? then return

    if instance.connected.false? and @job.attempts < 3
      raise 'The job failed!'
    else
      instance.shutdown
    end
  end

  def max_attempts
    3
  end

  def reschedule_at(current_time, attempts)
    current_time + 5.minutes
  end

end
```